I want to copy column data to cell one by one with time interval using app script
I want to copy column data to only one cell one by one with time interval using app script.



Column A
Column B




Cell 1



Cell 3



Cell 4



Cell 5




copy ColumnA1 to Column B1
wait 5 second
Copy columnA2 to Column B1
wait 5 second
Copy columnA3 to column B1
continue...
I want to do this automatic
I need app script code this.

function myFunk01() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    sh.getRange(i + 2,2).setValue(e);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
  });
}

Demo:

